# How to display the timeline using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a timeline but it's not displaying my design output. I have to display the first child after the image and next child before image with a full underline. I tried but my underline not displaying proper even image is not display the right way

Would you help me out in this?
I need a output like this.
[image]

```css
.timeline ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
 /* background: #fff;*/
 border-right: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
 
.timeline ul li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: inherit;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd),
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even){
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
  text-align:right;
  position:relative;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even){
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  clear:left;
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd):after,
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even):before{
background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/67/67347.png') no-repeat;
width: 24px;
height: 20px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
                  <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: use `li:nth-child(odd)` and `li:nth-child(even)` in your css

Comment: @bahmanparsamanesh, Yes, I added odd in place of 1 and even in place of 2n or 2n+1. now I am getting my image. but there is some issue with line

Comment: Yes I see. I solved it and post an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect or dynamic but it will get you on the right path.
use `nth-child(odd/even)` to select every second row

```css
li:nth-child(odd) {    
float: left;
border-right: thick solid #ff0000;

margin: 0px;
padding-right: 20px;
background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/67/67347.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-position-x: 254px;
background-position-y: 18px;
}
li:nth-child(even) {    
float: right;
border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
margin-right: 186px;
         
padding-left: 20px;
background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/67/67347.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-position-y: 18px;    
}
ul{
list-style: none;
}
li{
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
div{
width: 777px;
}
img{
width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
      <ul>                  
         <li>
             <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a>                         
         </li>  
            
         <li>                         
             <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a>   
         </li>    
             
         <li>
             <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a>                           
         </li>
            
         <li>                        
             <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a>                         
         </li>   
         
         <li>                         
             <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a>   
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,I have to display the image also.

Comment: Can we display background image using CSS instated of img tag?

Comment: The red line is jagged in Firefox.

Comment: @user9437856 i got the image to kinda work with only css now, but i do not recommend using it

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution :

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/xh9tf6aj/)

```css
.timeline ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
 /* background: #fff;*/
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) {
 border-right: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) {
 border-left: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
 
.timeline ul li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: inherit;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd){
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
  text-align:right;
  position:relative;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even){
  width:49.7%;
  float:right;
  clear:left;
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd):after,
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd):before{
background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/67/67347.png') no-repeat;
width: 24px;
height: 20px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I have to display the image in odd with after and even with before image. Also, check the underline, it's breaking when checking on a full page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of thing missing or wrong with your code.

- You applied the border on both the divs on the same side. I fixed this by giving them both a different border.
- To make sure the border was included within the size of the element I used `box-sizing: border-box;`.
- As with some of the other answers they became jagged so I applied a width to the element of `50% - half the border size` i.e. `width: calc(50% - 1px)`. This should always result in a straight line.
- You never made sure the actual `:before` would be displayed.  So i applied the same rules for the `:after` to the `:before`.
- Gave the `li` a small padding so it wouldn't be stuck to the border, resulting in some space for the image.

The code below should work the way you intended. As for margins and padding, you are ofcourse free to adjust them to your needs.

```css
.timeline ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
.timeline ul li::after, .timeline ul li::before {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 24px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd){
  float:left;
  clear:right;
  text-align:right;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff0000;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even){
  float:right;
  clear:left;
  text-align:left;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff0000;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd):after{
  background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/67/67347.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  right: -5px;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even):before{
  background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/67/67347.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
                  <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain me, what was the issue with my code?

Comment: @user9437856 added some explanation to the answer

Comment: @user9437856 If my answer or any of the other answers resolve your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a part of `CSS` as below: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skdfb591/2/)

```
.timeline ul li:nth-child(1), .timeline ul li:nth-child(2n+1){
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 5px inset black; //border
    left: -5px; //alignment
 }

 .timeline ul li:nth-child(2n){
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 5px inset black; //border
 }
```